# How to isolate component from activity when it needs start the intent for result?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to create a component whose task will be to provide photo file from camera intent.
Until now, i did those things in activity by starting another activity for result and waiting for it.
But now I want to use that component from business logic layer where is no access to UI layer (activities).
How to create a component that meets these requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In custom `Application` class make available `context` through create static getter for instance `App` class.

   ```
   public class App extends Application {
       private static App instance;

       @Override
       public void onCreate() {
           instance = this;
       }

       public static App getInstance(){
           return instance;
       }
   }
   ```

   **If you are using dependency injection I strongly recommend provide `App` class by it.**
2. Create an interface for component that describes what component can do. Here we have function `takePhoto()` and two another functions for *add* and *remove* listener.

   ```
   public interface PhotoTakerComponent {
       void takePhoto();
       void addListener(PhotoTakerListener listener);
       void removeListener(PhotoTakerListener listener);
   }
   ```
3. Implementation of `PhotoTakerComponent` will communicate with our biusness layer class by listener - `PhotoTakerListener`.

   ```
   public interface PhotoTakerListener {
       void onPhotoTaken(Boolean success, String path);
   }
   ```
4. Now create `PhotoTakerActivity`. This *activity* will be component internal class without layout. We will start it only for start correct intent and wait for reslut at `onActivityResult` method. After all this will be instantly finished. User will never see this activity because we will not inflate any layout.

   ```
   public class PhotoTakerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

       ...

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           ...

           Uri uri = Uri.parse(mFileName);

           Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
           intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, **uri**);

           if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
               startActivityForResult(intent, RequestImageCapture);
           }
       }

       @Override
       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
           super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

           if (requestCode == RequestImageCapture) {
               if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                   for (PhotoTakerListener listener: listeners) {
                       listener.onPhotoTaken(false, null);
                   }
               } else if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                   for (PhotoTakerListener listener: listeners){
                       listener.onPhotoTaken(true, mFileName);
                   }
               }
           }

           finish();
       }
   }
   ```
5. In the last step we must create implementation of `PhotoTakerComponent` interface where in `takePhoto()` method we starting internal `PhotoTakerActivity`.

   ```
   public class DefaultPhotoTakerComponent implements PhotoTakerComponent {
       private Context mApplicationContext;

       public DefaultPhotoTakerComponent() {
           mApplicationContext = App.getInstance().getApplicationContext();
       }

       @Override
       public void takePhoto() {
           if (mApplicationContext.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
               try {

                   ...

                   Intent intent = new Intent(mApplicationContext, PhotoTakerActivity.class);
                   intent.putExtra(PhotoTakerActivity.ExtraFileName, Uri.fromFile(image).toString());
                   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                   mApplicationContext.startActivity(intent);
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       }

       public void addListener(PhotoTakerListener listener){
           PhotoTakerActivity.addListener(listener);
       }

       public void removeListener(PhotoTakerListener listener){
           PhotoTakerActivity.removeListener(listener);
       }
   }
   ```

**Sample application is available on Github:**

For `Java` Android: [Here](https://github.com/Lonelywood/Android-Samples-IsolateComponents/tree/master/Android)
and for `C#` Xamarin.Android: [Here](https://github.com/Lonelywood/Android-Samples-IsolateComponents/tree/master/Xamarin)